# AngularJS with Microsoft Graph Group API

Tags: angularjs, office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

When I try to retrieve the Office365 Groups I'm member of using AngularJS HTTP Get. I always get a 400 - Bad Request error in Chrome. In IE I do get a result.

```
var endpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf/$/microsoft.graph.group?$filter=groupTypes/any(a:a eq 'unified')";

this.$http.get(endpoint, {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }
 }).then(function (result) {
     console.log(result);
}, function (error) {
     console.log("error:" + error);
});
```

Looks like the quotes in the URL are replaced with %27 and the Microsoft Graph/OData doesn't support this. I'll get the following error back:

```
Collection open properties are not supported in this release.
```

The JoinedGroups resource isn't available in the Microsoft Graph anymore. Is there another way to retrieve to Groups I am member of? Or is there another way to do this in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListMemberOf to get members of a group. here is a reference how to call the endpoint:
https://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list_members

You can use any falvor of JS client library to request o365 api. there is no limitation of which library you use as you have a correct request to the endpoint.

You can also use the graph explorer to make sure that you have a right request before coding it in AngularJS.

Graph explorer url: https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I could use 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf' to get the groups i'm member of and than filter them manually. Which is more efficient that retrieve all members of the groups. But I was looking into an option to filter it immediately using de REST/OData query with AngularJS. Also used the Graph Explorer, but haven't found another way yet as the one described in the MSDN documentation. But the quotes in the URL from documentation doens't work for me..

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 unified groups I’m member of: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf/$/microsoft.graph.group?$filter=groupTypes/any(a:a%20eq%20'unified')`

Comment: Also tried it with %20 instead of spaces, but same result. Quotes are replaced with %27 and not accepted by the REST endpoint.